# notify user account creation?

Tags: 8, users

I can't seem to find documentation for notifying a user via email after their account has been created by a script.

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();

$user->setPassword('xxx');
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail('xxx+'.time().'@gmail.com');
$user->setUsername('xxx'.time());

$user->set('init', 'email');
$user->set('langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_admin_langcode', $language);
$user->activate();

//$user->notify()? something?

$result = $user->save();
```

Comment: This is set under `/admin/config/people/accounts`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the configuration on admin in the `/admin/config/people/accounts` but if you want to notify the user programmatically without taking care of what is the config you can use `_user_mail_notify` function.

[_user_mail_notify documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/8.2.x)